# Tensorflow/Keras, How to convert tf.feature_column into input tensors?

Tags: keras, tensorflow

I have the following code to average embeddings for list of item-ids.
(Embedding is trained on review_meta_id_input, and used as look up for pirors_input and for getting average embedding)

```
 review_meta_id_input = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(1,), dtype='int32', name='review_meta_id')
 priors_input = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(None,), dtype='int32', name='priors') # array of ids
 item_embedding_layer = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(
     input_dim=100,      # max number
     output_dim=self.item_embedding_size,
     name='item')

 review_meta_id_embedding = item_embedding_layer(review_meta_id_input)
 selected = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(review_meta_id_embedding, priors_input)
 non_zero_count =  tf.cast(tf.math.count_nonzero(priors_input, axis=1), tf.float32)
 embedding_sum = tf.reduce_sum(selected, axis=1)
 item_average = tf.math.divide(embedding_sum, non_zero_count)
```

I also have some feature columns such as.. 
(I just thought feature_column looked cool, but not many documents to look for..)

```
  kid_youngest_month = feature_column.numeric_column("kid_youngest_month")
     kid_age_youngest_buckets = feature_column.bucketized_column(kid_youngest_month, boundaries=[12, 24, 36, 72, 96])
```

I'd like to define `[review_meta_id_iput, priors_input, (tensors from feature_columns)]` as an input to keras Model.

something like:

```
 inputs = [review_meta_id_input, priors_input] + feature_layer
 model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=o)
```

In order to get tensors from feature columns, the closest lead I have now is

```
fc_to_tensor = {fc: input_layer(features, [fc]) for fc in feature_columns}
```

from https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/17170

However I'm not sure what the `features` are in the code.
There's no clear example on https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/feature_column/input_layer either.

How should I construct the `features` variable for `fc_to_tensor` ?

Or is there a way to use `keras.layers.Input` and `feature_column` at the same time?

Or is there an alternative than tf.feature_column to do the bucketing as above? then I'll just drop the feature_column for now;

Answer (score 0):

I think my answer over there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56693937/tensorflow-how-to-convert-feature-column-to-vector might help you.

Look at

```
feature_layer = tf.keras.layers.DenseFeatures(feature_columns)
```